# How can I update 15 rows every 2 seconds?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update, rows

On an Oracle DB, if I have a table with an arbitrary number of rows. What is the simplest way of running an update query that will update the first 15 rows, then wait 2 seconds, then update the next 15 rows, then wait 2 seconds, then update the next 15 rows... and so on?

Comment: I'm more interested in another question: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write A PLSQL block and use `dbms_lock.sleep`.

Example:

```
Declare
abc varchar(50);
.
.
.
begin
for i ...... loop
.
.
dbms_lock.sleep(2);
end loop;
end;
/
```